# Unable to call activity using Toggle Status

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I am using `Toggle button` to call other `activity`, and using code which we use with normal android button to call another activity like this:

```
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {

                textMap.setText("Status: " + isChecked);
                String strMapStatus = textMap.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(TrackerActivity.this, strMapStatus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(strMapStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("viewall",arrayList);
                    Intent sendtosecond = new Intent(TrackerActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                    sendtosecond.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
                    startActivity(sendtosecond);
                }

            }
        });
```

I am getting Check status as "true" and "false" in `Toast` but unable to call **MapActivity**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
if(strMapStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
```

to

```
if(isChecked)
```